# How to calculate the inscribing circle that contains (intersecting) circles

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math, geometry

How do I calculate a smallest possible circle that includes a set of circles?
I know soddy circles, but they are circles of smaller circles that are tangent to each other.

The attached image shows 2 examples. As for the left image, the radii of the green and pink circle are equal, so the centerpoint of the wanted red circle is (pink.pos - green.pos) / 2. The radius is pink.radius + green.radius + (pink.pos - green.pos).magnitude.

But how can I write a generic algorithm for more than 2 circles?

As for the right example, getting the centerpoint of the red circle is not adequate when summing all positions and dividing by 4 because the raddii differ. Also notice the yellow one can be ignored because the radius and position of the red circle will always be the same, unless the yellow one gets out of the red circle.

[image: Two examples for the problem. The red circles contain all the circles or only tangent them. One could go further and create a larger inscribing circle with the 2 red circles.]

This is what my code looks but it gives wrong results.

```
public class Circle {
    public float radius;
    public Vector2 pos;
  
    public Circle(Vector2 pos, float radius){
        this.pos = pos;
        this.radius = radius;
    }
}

///<summary> 
///Calculates the radius and position of the smalles possible circle that fully includes all circles.
///</summary>
public static Circle InscribingCircle(List<Circle> circles){ 
    float newRadius = 0;
    Vector2 newPos = Vector2.zero;
    
    int count = circles.Count;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
        newRadius += circles[i].radius;
        
        newPos += circles[i].pos;
    }
    newPos.x /= count;
    newPos.y /= count;
    newRadius /= count;
    
    return new Circle(newPos, newRadius);
}
```

Comment: Well you are just calculating the average of all circle position and radius ... An inscribing circle however as you can see of course always has to be bigger or equal the biggest circles ^^

Comment: I think here is a ready to use solution [Find a minimal bounding circle of a set of points in C#](http://csharphelper.com/blog/2014/08/find-a-minimal-bounding-circle-of-a-set-of-points-in-c) you just have to sample "enough" points per circle

Comment: Ok this is more of a math problem but first off all you should not count small circles that does not  affect the total.  I don't know if this will work but find the center of all circles.  Find the biggest/farthest circle. Draw a line to that center to biggest circles center and add the radius and draw your circle. Now remove circles that does not intersect and inside the circle.  find the new center and do again until you can't go smaller and every starter circle is in it. I am not sure if this works alone  though.

Comment: Don't forget being biggest circle does not mean it will always affect the inscribing circle.  You can put a very big yellow circle in there.

Comment: @Xentios from the duplicate link you will see that this is a maths problem far from trivial to solve ;)